# What type of plot can I use in R to get the following effect?

Tags: r, graphics, plot

I am keeping track of events with a monthly granularity (where I am guaranteed no two events on the same day of the month, and about 3-4 events a month but with some empty months and some months going to 6 or even 7). The events are labelled and I would like the y-axis to represent a magnitude unique to each event while their placement along the x-axis the chronological order. So something like this:

```
                                 E
  B
              C
A               D                    
---------------------------------------------->
Jun-07    Jul-07    Aug-07    Sept-07......
```

If I label my points with full dates, how can I bucket them by month when I plot them? I use ggplot2/qplot

Comment: Sounds like it would be easiest to start with a scatterplot (x=time, y=magnitude) and modify to get the visual effect you want (no y axis, letters instead of points.  Something similar in ggplot2 (you want `geom_text`) is here: http://stats.stackexchange.com/a/14028/3488

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Does this get you what you want:

```
# Fake data
events = c('A','C','C','B','B')
magnitudes = c(1,3,2,4,2)
times = c('7/4/12','7/5/12','7/7/12','7/10/12','7/15/12')

# Convert times to appropriate date format
library(lubridate)
times = mdy(times)

# Using "pch=events" gives you the appropriate plot symbols at the
#  appropriate places
plot(times, magnitudes, pch=events)
```